# How can I change the coffeescript class extends style to cc.Class.extends({ator:function(){} ...})?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, extends

```
class  Son extends Father
```

as coffeescript to js:

```
Son = function(){ __extends=function(){...} .... Son::ator = function(){} return Son}
```

but I need this:

```
Son = Father.extends({ator:function (){}})
```

When the bassClass is not a coffee class, the native 'extends' is not used for everything. So 
can I use the new style 'extends' by changing the coffeescript code, and if so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "native extends" - the coffeescript one? And what is "new style extends"? And where is `Father.extends` defined?

Answer (score 0):

> I need this:
>
> ```
> Son = Father.extends({ator:function (){}})
> ```

I don't see what's wrong with using CoffeeScript's `extends`, but if you want to write code that compiles to the above just use

```
Son = Father.extends
    ator: () ->
```